# c# Using Combobox value to array

Tags: c#, arrays, events, combobox

Want to make make array with chosen by user combobox values.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {   
        InitializeComponent();
        Combobox.DisplayMemberPath = "Text";
        Combobox.SelectedValuePath = "Value";
        Combobox.Items.Add(new { Text = "String", Value = 0 });
        Combobox.Items.Add(new { Text = "String", Value = 1 });
    }
        string[] array = new string[30];
        bool gotResponse = false;
    }
    private void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoWork));
        thread.Start();
    }
    private void Next_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        gotResponse = true;
    }
    void DoWork()
    {
        for (int Step = 0; Step < 30; Step++)
        {
            while (!gotResponse)
            {

            }

            array[Step] = Combobox.SelectedValue.ToString();
            bool gotResponse = false;
        }
    }
```

I want to Create a array adding using Next_Click button arguments step by step to array. And Im stuck, plase help.
receive "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll"

Comment: `Combobox.Items.Add(new { Text = "Strin", Value = 0 });` should that be `String` and not `Strin`

Comment: I eaten the leather, no beag deal.

Comment: hopefully it tastes good..

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand why you are doing something like this. (weird)
But the problem can be caused by the fact that you don't set gotResponse to false after settings the value to array[Step].

Comment: forgot,true but it dosnt help, I hane edit the main question.

Comment: Ok, so what is your goal ? 
I don't understand why you are using a loop in a Window.
I don't know where Argumenty come from.
Why don't you do "the job" on Next_click event ?
And if you want to stil use an array (you can use a List if you don't want to manage the lenght) :
Remove the method DoWork.
Remove the Thread.
Just add a private int initialized to 0; `private int arrayPos = 0;`
And change Next_click to : 
`private void Next_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            array[arrayPos] = comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
            arrayPos++;
        }`